# Dropdown item with an img-thumbnail exceeds its container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Dropdown items contain an img-thumbnail and a button. These two elements are side by side without a space in between. The button exceeds both the dropdown item and dropdown.

How to fix this issue keeping the items relative width untouched ?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Reference</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="dropdownMenuReference" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-reference="parent">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuReference">
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> Something esle and something else</button>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Action</button>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
        <span> Separated link and Separated link</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Reference</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="dropdownMenuReference" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-reference="parent">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuReference">
    <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
      <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Action</button>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
      <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> Something esle and something else</button>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
      <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
      <span> Separated link, Separated link and Separated link</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want this problem to be fixed in whatever way you can but just do not use `fixed width` and do not break word/text.

Comment: What's your desired outcome?

Comment: @isherwood That the button or text does not exceed dropdown's width.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Do you want a shorter button? Do you want a wider menu? Do you want the buttons aligned? (Be specific, and put it in your question instead of a comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply `width: max-content` to each of your `ul` so the width of the menu will adapt to its content, please be aware that the `max-content` property is not fully supported by all the browsers (it is however supported by most used ones), more infos [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content).

Example below :

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Reference</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="dropdownMenuReference" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-reference="parent">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul style="width: max-content;" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuReference">
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> Something esle and something else</button>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
       <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> Something esle and something else</button>
  </li>
      <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
        <span> Separated link and Separated link</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Reference</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="dropdownMenuReference" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-reference="parent">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul style="width: max-content;" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuReference">
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> Something esle and something else</button>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
       <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> Something esle and something else</button>
  </li>
      <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
        <span> Separated link, Separated link and Separated link</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```